# Android: NullPointerException: cursoradapter, populating listview

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I have NullPointerException when i call method from ShowRecords class.
It works fine when i have the same method in DBAdapter and i call it in ShowRecords class.

Here is my DBAdapter class having method getAllMeter().

```
 //---------getting data from sqlite-------------


public Cursor getAllMeter() {
    Cursor c;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] All_Columns = new String[] { COLUMN_METER_ID, COLUMN_METER_DATE, COLUMN_METER_START, COLUMN_METER_END, COLUMN_METER_CAR_ID };
    c = db.query(TABLE_METER, All_Columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here is my MeterAdapter class. when i call getAllMeter() from DBAdapter class. it works fine i can populate listview

```
public class MeterAdapter extends Activity {
DBAdapter dbh;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter mycursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_records);
    dbh = new DBAdapter(this);
    populateListview();
}

public void populateListview() {

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = dbh.getAllMeter();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] fromfields = new String[] { 
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_DATE,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_START, 
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_END,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_CAR_ID };
    int[] tofields = new int[] { 
            R.id.meterdate, 
            R.id.meterstart,
            R.id.meterend,
            R.id.fk};
    mycursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_meter, cursor,
            fromfields, tofields, 0);
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Here is my ShowRecords class having method getMeterRecords()

```
public class ShowRecords extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
DBAdapter dbh;

Button show_result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showresult_pickdate);

    show_result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_showresult);

    show_result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ShowRecords.this, MeterAdapter.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public Cursor getMeterRecords() {

    dbh = new DBAdapter(ShowRecords.this);

    db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c;
    String[] All_Columns = new String[] { DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_ID,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_DATE, DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_START,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_END };
    c = db.query(DBAdapter.TABLE_METER, All_Columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here is MeterAdapter class where i call getMeter() from ShowRecord class

```
public class MeterAdapter extends Activity {
DBAdapter dbh;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter mycursor;
ShowRecords showRecords;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_records);
    //dbh = new DBAdapter(this);
    showRecords= new ShowRecords(); // referencing ShowRecords class
    populateListview();
}

public void populateListview() {

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = showRecords.getMeterRecords();
    //cursor = dbh.getAllMeter();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] fromfields = new String[] { 
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_DATE,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_START, 
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_END,
            DBAdapter.COLUMN_METER_CAR_ID };
    int[] tofields = new int[] { 
            R.id.meterdate, 
            R.id.meterstart,
            R.id.meterend,
            R.id.fk};
    mycursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_meter, cursor,
            fromfields, tofields, 0);
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

it gives me the following nullpointerException

```
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mscprojectimagebuttons/com.munawwar.sultan.cursoradapter.MeterAdapter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.munawwar.sultan.showrecordsdatewise.showrecordsBetweenDates.getMeterRecords(showrecordsBetweenDates.java:183)
  02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):    at com.munawwar.sultan.cursoradapter.MeterAdapter.populateListview(MeterAdapter.java:39)
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.munawwar.sultan.cursoradapter.MeterAdapter.onCreate(MeterAdapter.java:31)
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)  
 02-20 03:39:08.663: E/AndroidRuntime(392):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `ShowRecords` is not class. It's and `Activity`. You can't reference it.So better to add `getMeterRecords(..)` method in to `MeterAdapter  Activity`.

Comment: dbh = new DBAdapter(ShowRecords.this); change this line to  dbh = new DBAdapter(getActivity());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

> dbh = new DBAdapter(ShowRecords.this);

Line causing issue because `ShowRecords` Activity not running when calling `getMeterRecords` method by create object of `ShowRecords` in `MeterAdapter` class.

Just for testing add Context parameter in `getMeterRecords()` method like:

```
public Cursor getMeterRecords(Context context) {
    dbh = new DBAdapter(context);
    ...
}
```

Call `getMeterRecords` by passing context of `MeterAdapter` class:

```
cursor = showRecords.getMeterRecords(MeterAdapter.this);
```

So conclusion is no need to extend Activity in `ShowRecords` class if it as a utility class.

Comment: I got your point. but Actually i'm doing this in ShowRecords Activity because i'm having two TextView in this Activity "START DATE" and "END DATE" and i will make an query in getMeterRecords() of b/w date.
and thn call it in MeterAdapter Activity. 
can you guide me what should i do in that case?

Comment: @AsifKhan: just do it as : pass TextView values in intent when starting `MeterAdapter` activity and remove `getMeterRecords` method from `ShowRecords` and add it in `MeterAdapter` then use getIntent for getting both TextView values and pass it to query